# Angular 5 @Input property isn't a known property of component in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular5, lazy-loading

I am trying to lazy load existing components in the angular application. I have imported a module named notification in the login module. Notification is a child component used via its selector name in the login component.

But the problem is notification component not identifying  all @Input properties

Here is the error message

```
Can't bind to 'message' since it isn't a known property of 'app-notification'.
1. If 'app-notification' is an Angular component and it has 'message' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-notification' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Thank you in advance

Here is the code

Login moudle

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { LoginRoutingModule } from './login-routing.module';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { NotificationModule } from 'app/notification/notification.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, LoginRoutingModule, NotificationModule],
  declarations: [LoginComponent],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

Login.html

```
<app-notification [message]="notificationMessage" [type]="notificationType"></app-notification>
```

notification.ts

```
    @Input('message') set notificationMessage(message: string) {
        this._notificationMessage = message;
      }
  @Input('type') notificationType: string;
```

notification.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NotificationComponent } from './notification.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [NotificationComponent],
})
export class NotificationModule {}
```

Comment: try exporting NotificationComponent in NotificationModule

Answer (score 0):

**Notification module** is not **exporting** the notification component

Notification Module should be like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NotificationComponent } from './notification.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [NotificationComponent],
  exports:: [NotificationComponent]
})
export class NotificationModule {}
```

Comment: This should work, Can you share more details

Comment: There is some issue with angular version 5.2. I updated angular and it is working now